# Fitting mat-card inside mat-grid-tile

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to make the mat-card to resize with the mat-grid-tile. However, it seem when I reduce the size of the tab, the card doesn't fit the new size.

I tried to change my css to this, but it didn't work.

```css
mat-card {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gdgm7w?file=src/app/app.component.html

Is there a way to make the card shrink in size (like  does) when resizing the window?

------------------- Update---------------

Based on someone's answer I sat height for mat-grid-list and this made it kind of work but not when I increase the size of the tab.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3n3mjg?file=src/app/app.component.html

for instant when I go fullscreen with the tap the card loses parts of it.
https://angular-ivy-3n3mjg.stackblitz.io

Sadly I am not very familiar with css to know how to fix that.

Comment: Is it possible that you upload an image where it shoes what exactly the problem is and what you want to achieve? In the stackblitz I can see that the mat-card is resizing when window size changes.

Comment: It does resize but it hides most of the card parts for example the action buttons and the title. What I want is to show the whole card in a responsive way just like when the card is by itself and not in a grid-list.

Comment: Now the stackblitz also represents your problem. Thank you for adjusting! Nevertheless I am not sure whether mat-grid is suitable for your use-case. You would have to really adjust the styling of many tags in mat-card. The problem here is that mat-card is taking up as much space as there is content contained. mat-grid on the other hand is for fixing content size inside of it, which is kind of like a conflict. Maybe simple flexboxes without mat-grid are getting the job done in your case.